# How to do dynamic UI change in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to ask how to implement the UI change based on the button click. At below screenshots shown 1,2,3 are the toggle buttons.

[image]

When user click button 1, then it will display Form B UI.

[image]

When user click button 2, it will display image.

[image]

Comment: This is far too broad.  Try breaking this up into smaller questions, showing what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: in short: mvvm, contentpresenter control and datatemplate is your friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this xaml code separately and try.

```
<Border Width="500" Height="400" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border  Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"></Border>
        <TextBlock Name="FormA" Text="Form A" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
        <Border Name="FormBBoder" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"  Grid.Row="1"  Visibility="Collapsed" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"></Border>
        <TextBlock Name="FormB" Text="Form B" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <Border  Name="FormCBoder" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Collapsed"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"></Border>
        <TextBlock Text="Form  C" Name="FormC" Visibility="Collapsed"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <ToggleButton Content="1">
            <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <Int32Animation Storyboard.TargetName="FormA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0" ></Int32Animation>
                            <Int32Animation Storyboard.TargetName="FormA" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)" From="0" To="2" Duration="0:0:0" ></Int32Animation>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FormBBoder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FormB" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FormCBoder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FormC" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ToggleButton.Triggers>
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton Content="2" Grid.Column="1">
            <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FormBBoder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FormB" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ToggleButton.Triggers>
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton Content="3" Grid.Column="2">
            <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FormBBoder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FormB" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FormCBoder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FormC" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ToggleButton.Triggers>
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

**Result**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a form with all the elements. Set visibility on the image and form b to collapsed. On button 1 create an event that changes form b visibility to visible. On button 2 create an event that changes image visibility to visible.

A simple example:

Code in xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="1st element" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="hiddenElement" Visibility="Collapsed" Text="hiddenElement" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="btn" Content="Show 2nd element" Click="btn_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind

```
    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        hiddenElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

This should give you a basic idea of what to do.

Comment: I think you are on the right track here. Could you add some code demonstrating this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TabControl`

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="1">
        <!-- your content (Form A) here -->
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="2">
        <!-- your content (Form A,B) here -->
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="1">
        <!-- your content (Form A,B and image) here -->
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: I think the content from the other "buttons" should show as well, kind of like toggle buttons for UI. A tabcontrol won't do it

Answer (score 0):

Using the WPF `TabControl`

The WPF TabControl allows you to split your interface up into different areas, each accessible by clicking on the tab header, usually positioned at the top of the control.

[image]

[WPF TabControl](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/tabcontrol/using-the-tabcontrol/)

Comment: I think the content from the other "buttons" should show as well, kind of like toggle buttons for UI. A tabcontrol won't do it